# AutomationElement.FromHandle(IntPtr Handle) stops the application

Tags: c#, .net, automationelement

```
private string GetCurrentChromeUrl()
    {
        try
        {
            string url = null;

            int handle = GetForegroundWindow();
            AutomationElement elm = AutomationElement.FromHandle((IntPtr)handle);
            AutomationElement elmUrlBar = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
                  new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"));
            if (elmUrlBar != null)
            {
                AutomationPattern[] patterns = elmUrlBar.GetSupportedPatterns();
                if (patterns.Length > 0)
                {
                    ValuePattern val = (ValuePattern)elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0]);
                    url = val.Current.Value;
                    //break;
                }
            }
            return url;
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            return "";
        }
   }
```

I'm trying to find the URL from google chrome browser.

And  I'm using above code. It is work good in other application but in my case it stops my application.

But the main issue  is that it will work fine when I'm debugging it, so what wrong when no debugging.

please give your solutions.

thanx in advance

Comment: Any more information you can share? Also just guessing but is it perhaps a permission issue that doesn't show up due to debug settings?

Comment: ok I'm giving some aditional  information

Comment: I'm using this code in  void m_KeyboardHookManager_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {} when I just press one key my whole system goes hang and if i point the debug point at  AutomationElement elm = AutomationElement.FromHandle((IntPtr)handle); or before it then it works fine.but doesn't work after pointing debug point after that

Comment: hello sir now you can see my full code.

Comment: Does the `catch` statement catch any exception? And if so, what exception?

Comment: No sir there is no any exception.

Comment: there is no any problem if I debug this code.

Comment: i have similar code -  in chrome it is patterns[0]  (total - 1), in opera - patterns[1] (total - 2) so i would put not `elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0]);` but `((ValuePattern)elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[patterns.Length - 1])).Current.Value;`

Answer (score 1):

I'm passing through this, it happen cause of the intptr type, it depends of the build of the machine, sometime the windowhandle is too big for an intptr of a 32bits machine.